# How to make longer arrows from object to itself at xy-pic

Tags: lyx, arrows, xy-pic

I trying to control on the length of arrow from object to itself at `xymatrix` (xy-pic): for example -

[image]

This is what I get when I'm typing `*+++[o][F.]{a}\ar@(d,r)`

And this is what I get when I typing `*+++++[o][F.]{a}\ar@(d,r)`:
[image]

If I'll add more `+` it will give error....
Do you know how can I make the arrow longer?
I tried to add `@/_{2pc}/` but it doesn't help.

I'd like to do it for more options like: `@(u,d)` etc...

Here is the whole file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\L{$\SelectTips{eu}{10}\xymatrix{\\
*+++++[o][F.]{a}\ar`urd[r] & *++[o]{}
}
$}
\end{document}
```

Here is another one:

```
% Preview preamble

%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Please provide us with a full MWE. Thank you.

Comment: What is MWE? You're welcome! :-)

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You just posted one, I guess. I will see now, if it is minimal and compilable.

Comment: I cannot compile this. Please try to get rid of special fonts, languages, characters. Just show us the minimum which is needed in order to get your first or second image. If possible make it compilable with pdfLaTeX. All this just in order to make it easy for us to help you. We can spot errors easier and everybody will be able to compile your code on whatever system.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - I post a new one... Please tell me if it's works fine.. thank you!

Comment: So the problem doesn't occur if you aren't typesetting Hebrew or if your document is UTF8 encoded? I cannot tell whether you are using XeTeX and erroneously loading **inputenc** and **fontenc** or if you are using pdfTeX and unnecessarily including a fix for XeTeX.  Also why use the fix *before* loading **babel** if the fix is coded conditionally and the conditional test is designed to see if **babel** is loaded? That doesn't make any sense. Either the conditional is pointless or **babel** should be loaded first. Note that XeTeX assumes documents are UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before with endomorphisms of things with a long name. Its solution is the one I believe you are looking for (or at least a good attempt), I moved the source starting point and the target ending point of the arrow to be at the edge of the name.

If the name is big enough and you don't have `[]!<5mm,0mm>;[]!<5mm,0mm>` you even get an error as you mentioned.

```
\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix{
S\ar@(ur,dr)^-{t}
}}}\qquad\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix{
\mathcal{B}(S,X)\ar@(ur,dr)[]!<5mm,0mm>;[]!<5mm,0mm>^-{\mathcal{B}(t,X)}
}}}
```

I believe you can adapt this solution to your example. This is how it looks.[image]